# Convert Hash to specific string format in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, net-http

I would like to convert a hash: `{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}` into a string which looks like this: `'[{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}]'`

Background: I'm making an API call from my rails Controller. 
The curl equivalent of this request is `curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'valid_uri' --data '[{"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}]'`

So, to convert this in ruby, I tried the following:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse(VALID_URI)
header = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
data = {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
request.body = Array.wrap(data1.to_s.gsub('=>',':')).to_s
response = http.request(request)
```

However, the format of `request.body` doesn't match the format of data in curl request which results in **Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request**

Can someone please explain how can I achieve this? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the json module:

```
require "json"
h=[{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}]
string=h.to_json # => [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I was under the impression that to_json works only with Hash. Thanks!

Comment: You can convert any data-structur to json, arrays of arrays of hashes with arrays inside... By the way - do you know jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ . its to work with json data on commandline.